# Trouble setting radiobuttons with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn to use React.  My experiments were going well until I tried to use 2 radio buttons.  The code below shows both buttons as being "on" when I was expecting the "Or" button to be "off.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            operator: 'And',
            andSelected: 'true',
            orSelected: 'false'
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="search-bar">     
                <input type='radio' group='andor' defaultChecked={this.state.andSelected} />
                And
                <input type='radio' group='andor' defaultChecked={this.state.orSelected} />
                Or
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Note: I removed the click handlers to make the broken code simpler to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defaultChecked` prop expects a `boolean`. Passing a **non-empty** `string` will always evaluate to `true` - radios will be set to *checked*.

```
this.state = {
  operator: 'And',
  andSelected: true,
  orSelected: false
}
```